# Flash Keon with firefox OS 1.2

Tags: firefox-os

I am having problems trying to flash my device with 1.2 in order for me to start using the device for dev.

I have Android SDK installed.

When I run the following command in Terminal -

```
./flash_mac.sh
```

I get this message back -

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
```

If I run this command -

```
adb devices
```

I get the following back -

```
List of devices attached 
full_keon   device
```

Can anyone help me sort this?

Thnaks
Rory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to flash the device, I simply re-connected the USB cable while Daemon was being started again.

Obviously anyone else finding this issue, I imagine they will need to update ADB Server.

Not sure how to. As I literally just installed it via Android SDK.

Thanks
Rory

Comment: you should also check your cable and try a different one. This kind of thing could also happen with a flaky usb cable.

Comment: Notice that you don't need to install Android SDK: just use the adb that comes zipped along with the image files downloaded from geeksphone page: http://downloads.geeksphone.com/keon/v1.2/latest_v1.2.html I flashed my Keon using it.

Comment: May I suggest you flash your device with 1.3 instead?  IIRC, the only consumer device running 1.2 is the Revolution, and that only if the user reflashes it.